# How can I delete local content from a game not in my list in Steam?

Tags: steam

I played the free weekend for Call of Duty Black Ops and I decided not to buy it.

However, now I have a folder taking up 8 GB of my SSD space in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\call of duty black ops`.

The game is not listed on my game list in steam (where I could right-click and select "delete local content")

Is it safe to delete that folder directly? Is there another folder I could delete to recover more space? Is there a way to do it from Steam (this would be preferred)?

Comment: If you can see it in the installed programs list (Programs and Features) you can try uninstalling it there. If not, then you can safely delete the folder.

Comment: @Bora, it's not listed there either

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [Steam browser protocol](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol) to uninstall it:

> `steam://uninstall/<id>`
>   Deletes the specified apps' cache files.

Generally you can find the ID you need by looking at the URL of its Steam store page — for example, [http://store.steampowered.com/app/**42700**/](http://store.steampowered.com/app/42700/).

Call of Duty: Black Ops' ID is **42700**, so the link would be `steam://uninstall/42700`. Enter that into your browser's address bar or the Windows Run dialog (Win+R).

You can also pass it directly to the Steam executable as an argument:

```
Steam.exe "steam://uninstall/<id>"
```

In this case, it left behind a few files (~10 MB for me). Those can safely be deleted.

- folder: `steamapps\common\call of duty black ops`
- file: `steamapps\call of duty black ops mp binaries.ncf`

The multiplayer component actually has a separate ID (**42710**); uninstalling that ID did nothing for me, but you may want to try anyway, just to be sure.

Comment: Nice, that worked. Where do I see the id for a specific app?

Comment: @JuanManuel On its Steam store page, generally. It's in the URL. (Example: `http://store.steampowered.com/app/42700`)