# Replacing region-locked games with global on Steam

Tags: steam, region-lock

A few months back I bought the "Polish-only" version of Black Ops 2 and replaced the Polish language files with the English manually. Because I'm tired of doing this, I wondered if I would be able to buy a new global BO2 key from a third-party retailer and activate the key on Steam "on top" of my original game, gaining access to download the English language files?

Comment: Just to be sure: [You *definitely* don't have any other option than "Polish" in Steam?](http://i.imgur.com/MqiReVm.png)

Comment: Yes, I have, but if I try and use any other language I'm unable to as it won't let me download it

Comment: Does Steam give you any error message or similar when you try to download another language, or why do you say it won't let you? By the way, normally I'd suggest you contact Steam Support, but that's likely a waste of your time. Steam Support is slower than a lethargic snail and less helpful than chewing gum stains on the ground.

Comment: Well, it just dosen't download the english files, even if I select English and "Verify the game cache", and when I start the game I get the "fonts/720/consolefont" error (probably because of the missing files). I also tried and contact steam support, but as you said, they're basically snails over there...

Comment: I assume that you're referring to [Black Ops 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/202970/Call_of_Duty_Black_Ops_II/) with "BO2".

Answer (score 1):

You can now remove games from your account with [Steam Help](http://help.steampowered.com), please see [this answer by `r3tr0 t3h PeNgU1N oF d00m`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246442/87186) if you aren't sure how to do it.

You can use that to remove the old polish game and activate the global key.