# Will sending my friend a game as a gift remove it from my Library?

Tags: steam

So I bought Terraria from steam, and I want to send a copy to my friend for his birthday as a gift. Will doing this delete Terraria from my computer or just buy a whole new version of it for him?

Comment: If you chose the option to buy the game for yourself, then it is yours, and cannot be gifted. Otherwise, you should find the game in your inventory as an item, which you can then gift to your firned

Comment: Could you please accept one of the three answers? Our answers are clearly good by the vote count on all three.

Answer (score 16):

If you already have the game, then purchase your second copy by selecting the option to buy it as a gift. This will put a copy of the game in your steam inventory and will not affect your copy of the game at all. Go into your steam inventory and select the game, then select the option to send it, either through your friends list or through e-mail.

Comment: IIRC, unless you buy a 4-pack or something, Steam will ask you who to gift it to immediately, rather than you having to go through the inventory, but I haven't actually done that in a while.

Comment: @MrLemon You have 3 options when you purchase a gift through Steam:  1. Send by email. 2. Send directly through Steam (this gives you a list of all the friends on your friend list including orange text noting if they own the game or blue text noting if it's on their wishlist). 3. Put it into your inventory.

Answer (score 9):

If you are purchasing from the store it will have two buttons to click on

Purchase for myself
and
Purchase as a gift

If you have already purchased it for yourself then the Purchase for myself will be grayed out and you can only purchase the game as a gift.

The game can either be sent to him via email,
Through steam as friends(No need to open a trade window, also sends by email)
Kept in your inventory (To be gifted or traded later)

Comment: I just realized that lewlcat posted the same answer as me. Just up vote him instead. I'll leave this post here for extra clarification.

Comment: It's all good ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can not gift games that are in your library. You can only gift 'non-active' copies of a game. Such as a gift item in your inventory. If you don't have the game yourself yet you can 'unwrap' the gift to add it to your library but you would not be able to gift it anymore.
If you have the game in your library and purchased a second copy you should be able to give it to your friend. It will not be removed from your library.

Normally you can not remove any game from your library. This functionality came recently to steam but requires you to contact the steam support.
Check out [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/79346/56015) for more details about how to remove a game from your library (which is not what you want I suppose).