# Can I have one steam account with 5 games and second steam account with no games on the same PC?

Tags: steam, pc

I want to have an account from which I won't be recognised as another account. I already have several games on my new account which kinda gives me away.

Comment: Do you mean the second account not using family sharing games?

Comment: What possible motivation do you have to do this? Is somebody stalking you on Steam?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can log in to more than one Steam account from the same PC. [From Steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8963-EIKC-3767):

> Yes, you can access different Steam accounts from one computer. However, you may only access one account at a time.
>   The accounts will share the core files for any games the accounts have in common, but each account will maintain its own custom content and configuration files.

I'm not sure why you're worried about someone figuring out what your second account is. First off, I don't think you can actually play those 5 games from the account that doesn't have any. Secondly, there are millions of Steam users, so I don't think anyone is going to figure out your secret identity unless you do something that makes it obvious you're controlling both, such as adding the same friends, making similar-style forum posts, etc.

Comment: I just want to have a completely different account and I have these games in my library and I can't even launch them, so how do I delete them from my library?

Comment: @Gueeeest See [How do I remove a Steam game from my library?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30322/how-do-i-remove-a-steam-game-from-my-library)

Comment: @Gueeeest If you're going to ask for help with something, I might recommend actually being willing to receive help.

Answer (score 1):

#### In a word, yes.

> ### Can I use multiple Steam accounts on one computer?
>
> ---
>
> Yes, you can access different Steam accounts from one computer. However, you may only access one account at a time.
>
> The accounts will share the core files for any games the accounts have in common, but each account will maintain its own custom content and configuration files.

There's no particular way for anyone viewing the accounts through Steam to know both accounts are owned by the same real person, unless you do something to give yourself away.

Source: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8963-EIKC-3767#onemachine

Answer (score 0):

Steam games that are installed on the PC show up on that PC on other accounts, but aren't playable.  It says basically "Hey these games are already installed!  If you buy them, you won't even have to wait for them to install to play them!"  They are not in your library and only you (and other Steam users who are physically using your PC, in the event your PC is shared) can see them.  Other Steam users online cannot see those games on the account that doesn't own them.