# Is there a way to hide that you own a game in the Steam store?

Tags: steam

I have game details set to private in my profile, but when others look at a game I own in the Steam store, they can still see if I own the game or have added it to my wishlist. Is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: Steam has since updated their app to allow making games private when purchasing or playing. I have updated the selected answer reflecting that.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**Update [5th of March, 2024]:** You can now hide the game you want when you are purchasing or playing a game. You can read the [official blog post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/593110/eventcomments/4306075476942399844) to know more info.

When purchasing a game, the new cart will have a dropdown with the option to make it a private purchase. This will make it so that your purchase will not appear on everyone's timeline.
[image: Private cart]

When playing a game, you can go to your library, right click on a game and under the manage options, there will be an option to mark is as a private game. This will make it so that the game you mark as private will not appear on any other people on their timelines and other pages.
[image: Private game]

**Edit [27th Nov, 2023]:**
Setting your profile to private now hides others from seeing if you own a game from that game's store page. I checked again recently using the same method I initially used and saw that the game's ownership is hidden from your friends if you set your profile to private. This seems to have been quietly updated some time ago without any announcements. Also worth noting that Steam seems to be experimenting with a method on how to hide your game from others by enabling a setting from your library. As of now, this method isn't available to the public yet.

**Initial Answer:**
I tested this now using two accounts. And sadly, as of this writing, you can't seem to hide your owned/wishlisted games from your Steam friends on the games' specific store pages. This seems like an oversight on Valve's part since you can already hide owned/wishlisted games from your profile page using the privacy settings. That completely blocks them off from appearing on your profile. However, changing privacy setting doesn't seem to affect showing your ownership/wishlist status on the game's page.

This is trying to access a friend's wishlist when their profile is set to private. As you can see, the games are hidden as they should be.

[image]

And below is what you see when you visit a page of a game that your friend owns. The friend's profile privacy is set to "friends only" and the "keep my total playtime private" option is turned off. As you can see, it shows your friend's name and the total time they played the game.

[image]

This is what you see when you visit the same page when the friend's profile privacy is set to "friends only", but with the "keep my total playtime private" option turned on. It shows the friend who owns the game, but the game time is not shown. As it should be.

[image]

Finally, this is the same page, but with the friend's profile privacy set to "private". It supposedly shouldn't display anything, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

[image]

I think it's better if you contact [Steam support](https://help.steampowered.com/) regarding this and tell them. This seems like an oversight on Valve's part.

**Edit [15th Jan, 2021]:** I contacted Steam support on this issue. Seems like the issue would be fixed if more users made Valve aware of it using [Official Steam Feedback](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/10/), [Official Steam Help](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/), and [Steam Subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/).

[image]

Comment: An issue that extends from this: Your recommended games never forget what you've played, even if you've wiped the undesirable games in every way that you could think of.

Comment: Does that include a GDPR request to be forgotten, @J.Mini?

Comment: @AdamBarnes Can't say that I've ever tried that. Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Almost definitely not.  I also haven't tried.

Comment: Steam: We're sorry, but you cannot hide Hentai Simulator from your friends at this time.

Comment: @Coreus I'd bet on everything I own that that is the story behind this question

Comment: This has now been updated. Setting your account to private hides your game ownership from that game's store page from your friends. I have edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Looks like the beta client added a way instead of setting your account to private: https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/593110/view/3901870709962551195 I expect it will make its way to the stable release soon

Comment: Yeah, I will definitely update the answer once this feature comes to the stable build.

Comment: So, is there anything about a game's ownership that's still imposssible to hide in a game-specific manner?

Comment: There is now an official way of hiding a game by right-clicking it and checking its property, even without beta program. You can even go as far as hiding its activities from your contact (achievements and screenshots I suppose)

Answer (score 16):

While it's a decidedly sub-optimal (and somewhat-obvious) solution, there is one work-around to this if the game you don't want to be displayed is one that you haven't purchased yet:

Set up a second Steam account and use that account to purchase the game.

Then just don't add your friends to said second account.

Comment: Pretty much like having a personal e-mail account and a professional one, actually.

Answer (score 6):

Reposting my (now deleted) comment as an answer.

Not much of a solution, but you can follow [the following answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246442/226066) to "permanently" remove a game from your library. That will effectively behave as if you never had the game, and the store page won't say that you have the game in your library anymore, which gives you the impression that you would have to buy it again if you want to have it in your library again (which isn't the case; see below the quote).

Quote from the answer:

> Steps
>
> 1. Log into Steam Support
> 2. Select Games, Software, etc.,
> 3. Select the game from the search function that shows up
> 4. Select the option: I want to permanently remove this game from my
>    account.
> 5. Select the option: Ok, remove the listed games from my account
>    permanently.
> 6. Repeat as many times as you have games you'd like to get rid of.

Although Steam says it's "permanent", it isn't. You can cancel the removal (e.g. if you return on the support page for that game, you are prompted whether or not you want to put the game back in your library). Which means you can use the permanent removal feature as a way to toggle the game on or off whenever you want.

The only problem to this solution in your case is, you would have to cancel the removal everytime you want to play the game that was removed. Otherwise, it is an effective way of hiding away a game you own when you are not playing it (or if you don't ever intend to play it).

Comment: Maybe you should go into more depth about "cancel a removal".  I would have assumed removing a game means you would have to buy it a second time.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yeah, I almost though the same the first time I tried, because it looked like you couldn't re-enable it again. But then I tried the same steps again and realised I could undo it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I just edited it, met le know whether or not it's more clear know.

Comment: Yes, much better!