# How do I completely remove a game demo from steam?

Tags: steam

I have uninstalled the Torchlight II Demo from my steam library, But it still displays on the right-click menu of the steam system tray icon. How to remove it from the right-click menu?

[image]

- Edit 1, Add some details.

When I search for "Torchlight II Demo" on the Steam support page, the option "I want to permanently delete this game from my account" does not appear

[image]

Comment: [From the linked answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/181699/203077). Always been the best way.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing it in your taskbar because it was one of the five most recently played games you own. Once a game has been uninstalled from your library, if you do not want to ever play it again, you need to disassociate it with your steam account.

You can do this by first navigating to
Help > Steam Support

[image: Help dropdown with Steam Support option highlighted.]

You should now see a page that looks like this:
[image: The steam support homepage.]

What we want to do is navigate down to the search box (highlighted in red) and type in the name of the game, in your case Torchlight II Demo

Once you have found Torchlight II Demo you will need to click on it.

You will see a list of options. (I am removing the stanley parable demo from my library for the sake of this demonstration)
The last option on the list should say

> I want to permanently remove this game from my account

[image: The steam support page of The Stanley Parable Demo, with various options for assistance.]

Once you select this and confirm it, the game will be disassociated with your steam account. The change may be immediate, but if not - try restarting steam.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't find the **I want to permanently remove this game from my account** option, I also edited the question and put the search result