# Can't delete steam folders

Tags: steam

I'm not sure if this falls into the "gaming" catorgory but it's for the purpose of gaming. So there was a problem with one of my game files so I deleted part of the game, realized I messed up, then went to delete the whole game. That part doesn't matter. But when I went to delete the folder from the "common" section in steam, it said I needed permission from DESKTOP-(serial number)/(my username). I went through the permissions of the folder, changed a ton of stuff, and I still can't delete the folder. The game doesn't appear in steam, but the folder is still on my computer, taking up space. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does your Windows user account have Administrator privileges? Did you install the game with a different user account?

Comment: You could try deleting it with command prompt. Try some tutorials.

Comment: [May be of relevance, a list of ideas of how to delete stubborn files](https://www.howtogeek.com/128680/how-to-delete-move-or-rename-locked-files-in-windows/)

Comment: Will using Steam's uninstall function not work?

Comment: @CommandoAir The game is no longer in my steam library but still on my computer

Comment: This thread sounds similar to yours: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24439/how-can-i-delete-local-content-from-a-game-not-in-my-list-in-steam?rq=1 Does any of this help?

Comment: @Bucky The game should still be in your library if you installed through steam, even if it's a F2P game

Answer (score 1):

Booting to safe mode to delete the folder did the trick for me.